# How to return maximum of value in a tuple within a list within a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

This is an excercise from the book Python Workout by R.M Lerner.

I'm struggling to return a maximum value of the following code:

```
def most_repeating_word(ls):
    listed = [x for x in ls.split()]
    outcome = {}
   
    for word in listed:
        max_char = []
        char_set = []
        for char in word:
            if char not in char_set:
                char_set.append(char)
                count = word.count(char)
                max_char.append((char,count))
        
        outcome[word] = (max_char)

    return max(outcome, key = lambda x: x[1])

most_repeating_word('this is an elementary test example')
```

The function should return the word with highest repeating element, in this case "elementary" with e=3, but it returns "example".

I think the reason is that it compares second letters of the words, and returns 'x' as the max. I fail to understand how to access the tuples values. Using `outcome.values` in the return part does not help.

Comment: Why asking us? Isn't there a solution in the book?

Comment: What you do is to return the word with max char at index 1. In this case - `x` in `example`

Comment: This would be a bit easier if you stored (count, char) instead of (char, count).

Comment: You could also make use of `collections.Counter()` and its `most_common()` method.

Comment: Hint: you need to use `max` twice. First, for each word find the "maximum" letter with its count, second, find the "maximum" word according to the count of the "maximum" letter. Alternatively, make a different data structure where you store pairs (count, list of words having this count).

Comment: *buhtz* : the solution provided there used collections and most_common(), as *Barmar* pointed out as a potentional option,  I wanted to solve it using my own way, though I didn't know how to finish it. I think some of the recommendations work, thanks to @mkrieger1 . Perhaps one question remains. Having this datastructure ``` {key: [ word,(y,x)] } ``` , how does one acces the x value without using a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `outcome` is a dictionary of lists of tuples, you need two `max()` to find the word with the highest repeating element. The first `max()` finds the count of the highest repeating element in a word, and the second `max()` finds the word with the highest count.

Preserving the data structure you use, the `key` argument needs to look like this: `lambda word_maxchar: max(word_maxchar[1], key = lambda char_count: char_count[1])[1]`. The whole code would look like this:

```py
def most_repeating_word(ls):
    listed = [x for x in ls.split()]
    outcome = {}
   
    for word in listed:
        max_char = []
        char_set = []
        for char in word:
            if char not in char_set:
                char_set.append(char)
                count = word.count(char)
                max_char.append((char,count))
        
        outcome[word] = (max_char)

    return max(outcome.items(), key = lambda word_maxchar: max(word_maxchar[1], key = lambda char_count: char_count[1])[1])[0]

most_repeating_word('this is an elementary test example')
```

Also note that in order to iterate over both keys and values of a dictionary, you need to use `outcome.items()`.

With a little modification of your data structure, we can achieve slightly better readability of the code:

```py
def most_repeating_word(ls):
    listed = [x for x in ls.split()]
    outcome = {}
   
    for word in listed:
        max_char = []
        char_set = []
        for char in word:
            if char not in char_set:
                char_set.append(char)
                count = word.count(char)
                max_char.append((char,count))
            
        
        outcome[word] = max(max_char, key = lambda char_count: char_count[1])

    return max(outcome.items(), key = lambda x: x[1][1])[0]

most_repeating_word('this is an elementary test example')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `for loop` on `outcome` dictionary to check which letter in which word repeated the most.

### The code

```
def most_repeating_word(ls):
    listed = [x for x in ls.split()]
    outcome = {}
   
    for word in listed:
        max_char = []
        char_set = []
        for char in word:
            if char not in char_set:
                char_set.append(char)
                count = word.count(char)
                max_char.append((char,count))
        
        outcome[word] = (max_char)
    
    repeating_word = ''
    repeating_letter = ''
    max_char_count = 0
    for key in outcome:
        for letter in outcome[key]:
            if letter[1] > max_char_count:
                repeating_word = key
                repeating_letter = letter[0]
                max_char_count = letter[1]

    return [repeating_word, repeating_letter, max_char_count]


data = most_repeating_word('this is an elementary test example')

print(f"The word {data[0]} ham most repeated letter {data[1]} which occurs {data[2]} times")
```

### Output

```
The word elementary ham most repeated letter e which occurs 3 times
```